# Why my PCis generating invalid quantity of pixels?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am facing very weird issue when I am converting image into pixels in my PC it is giving invalid quantity of pixels which is not allowing me to convert those pixels back to image.

**Image To Pixels**

```
    from PIL import Image
import numpy
def giveArrayOfImage(img):
    empty=[]
    pic = Image.open(img)
    width ,height = pic.size
    res=[width,height]
    empty.append(res)
    pixel = numpy.asarray(pic)
    for i in range(len(pixel)):
        for j in range(len(pixel[0])):
            empty.append(pixel[i][j])
    return empty
oneDArray = giveArrayOfImage("check.jpg")
md = open('nt1.txt','a')
for i in range(len(oneDArray)):
        for j in range(len(oneDArray[i])):
            md.write(str(oneDArray[i][j])+'\n')
```

**Pixels To Image**

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2

openFile = open('input.txt')
readingline = openFile.readlines()
w, h = int(readingline[0]), int(readingline[1])
print(w,h)
ab = readingline[2:]
realList = []
for i in range(len(ab)):
    realList.append(int(ab[i].strip('\n')))

ar = np.array(realList)
ab = ar.reshape(w,h,3)
print(ab)

cv2.imwrite("updated.jpg",ab)
```

here is the exception if I am using the same code for converting picture to pixels and pixels to picture in my friend's PC it is working as fine as it should but I don't know why it is not working fine for me Its something not converting all pixels. I used same IDE versions for PC and my fiend's PC.
[image]

On the left side that text file is generated by my friend's PC on right side is generated by my PC
I am using version 3.9.

Comment: you should use `print()` to see values in variables. OR maybe you get problem because you didn't close file `md.close()`, System doesn't have to send data directly to file but it can keep them in buffer and send it when you close file - and if you don't close file then it could forget to save some data.

Comment: Thanksssssss Mannnn <3 <3